# Exploding a GeoDataFrame Pandas-style

Tags: pandas, geopandas

I understand that Geopandas uses Pandas' implementation under the hood. I'm trying to [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) a GeoDataFrame in Pandas style, but Geopandas overrides it with its own [`explode()`](https://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=explode#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode), working on geometries only. Is it possible to access Pandas `explode()` anyway?

Comment: Try `geoDf.apply(pd.Series.explode)`?

Comment: @cs95 Thanks, it looks like it is exploding in the correct way.